# Unity 4.3 + Android - I Need to Update Texture2D or RenderTexture at least 30 FPS at 1080 x 1920

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, unity-game-engine

**Quick Note** - If you have Unity/Android code that will play a **video stream h264, NOT the full video**, at 30+ FPS on the Unity side and can share it, that would save me!

**Description:**
I have Unity Pro 4.3.  The easy first approach is to create an array of Color32 [1080*1920] and assigning the elements to values created via a mathematical function.  The **Main Goal** is creating a Texture2D and using the array of colors for the pixels and being able to update them frame to frame at 30+ FPS.  Here are my results as of now:

**Texture2D Unity Side Only:**

- The assignment of the texture is not an issue.
- The use of Apply() is the big problem.  This is needed to actually update the texture.
- This runs at 0.5 FPS using a 1080 x 1920 texture. Of course too slow.

**Texture2D Between Unity and Android Side:**

- I have seen and attempted use of Android Java OpenGL ES Examples.
- This sounded and **still sounds** like the best approach if I am able to find the fix.
- I am passing the "pointer/ID" of the Texture2D to the Java Side via a bridge.
- Attempting to use the "pointer/ID" to update the Texture2D on the Java side using:
  `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturePtr);`
  `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, s_resolutionWidth, s_resolutionHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);`
- Using this "pointer/ID", I am able to make numerous calls that say it is all should be legitimate on the Java side before and after the GL calls.
- This had claims that it was the answer, but this has no affect until I use Apply() on the Unity side, which of course ruins it.
- My assumption is that the Java code has changed and I need to figure out what will fix my problem.

**RenderTexture:**

- This is what I have also seen as a potential answer.
- It claims to have quicker updating with Texture changes, but it appears to only set textures via a camera.
- I am wanting to update the RenderTextures with the simple 1080 frames mathematically calculated at least 30 FPS.
- The only way that I have found to do this is to unfortunately use a Texture2D and of course Apply() is needed!
- So as of right now, this seems close to usable, but all in all not usable.

I really need to know the best approach to updating textures in Unity at 30 FPS. Once I know how to do this, even in the simplest of forms, I would be able to make progress.

Comment: You might have to bite the bullet and pay for Unity Pro so you can use [movie textures](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/VideoFiles.html)  There  aren't a lot of community video scripts for Unity free and 30FPS is asking a lot.  You could start by making sure your textures are powers of 2, that gives a little performance boost.

Comment: I have unity pro.  As the description goes, I have to mess with all of the individual streams of a movie.  A movie can have numerous streams of video, sound and other streams all created and running in unison.  Because of this, I need the ability to change streams and show data we create in our own data streams. I have this working specifically on the droid, I just need to find a way to move the buffers of data from the stream to Unity and update the main texture.

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect to get anywhere close to 30 fps using the standard glTexImage2D() function because it copies and converts every image which makes it too slow.  That function is intended only for static images, which are loaded once and used many times.  The Android platform avoids this function by using the EGL Image Extension instead and apps can do the same.  However, it does require native code.  This article gives an introduction and example code for Android:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-opengl-es-to-accelerate-apps-with-legacy-2d-guis

Comment: I truly appreciate your quick response!  I have only had time to do a brisk run-through, but I assume you know this situation very well.  I will be reading through it tonight and I will see how it will apply to my situation.  I have one quick question, which you may or may not have an answer to.  Will this approach allow me to directly display this in on the Unity side or will I need to somehow get the Unity level to be transparent other than the UI so that the quickly changing textures are seen?

Comment: I know OpenGL ES on Android well, but I don't know Unity.  My main reason for trying to help is that I am very curious to read what you learn about this, so please be sure to share!